# VueJS transitions not working without setTimeout

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, css-transitions

I have some code to slide out a menu which works:

```
      Vue.set(this.filterStyles, filterIndex, {
        display: "block",
        height: "auto",
      });

      let filterValuesElHeight;
      Vue.nextTick().then(() => {
        let filterValuesEl = document.getElementById('parent-filter-values-' + filterIndex);
        filterValuesElHeight = filterValuesEl.clientHeight;

        Vue.set(this.filterStyles, filterIndex, {
          height: 0,
          display: "block"
        });

        return Vue.nextTick();
      }).then(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          Vue.set(this.filterStyles, filterIndex, {
            height: filterValuesElHeight + "px",
            display: "block"
          });
        }, 10);
      });
```

Initially the menu is setup with the following rules:

```
display: none;
height: 0;
transition: all 500ms;
```

The first Vue.set sets the height to auto so a accurate height can be taken with filterValuesEl.clientHeight

On the next tick the height is returned back to 0 then finally on the last tick it's set to its natural height.

However, it seems Vue.nextTick() isn't enough although I noticed adding an extremely small timeout seems to do the job. This works but feels quite messy. I was hoping someone might have a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you're using `filterStyles` in a template, something like: `:style="filterStyles"`. If that's the case, then

```
Vue.set(this.filterStyles, filterIndex, {
    display: "block",
    height: "auto",
});
```

won't actually set the height to `auto` immediately. Rather, it updates the component's data, and that update will be reflected in the DOM after a `nextTick()`. So, in effect, your code is off by one tick.

Stacking a series of `nextTick` calls one after the other is probably a bad practice, however. If, for example, the component is removed during the series, you'll be left with a dangling reference.

You could avoid all those ticks by just setting the style directly in order to measure its natural height. If the element has `ref="filter"` attribute, for example, then something like:

```
this.$refs.filter.style.height = "auto";
filterValuesElHeight = this.$refs.filter.clientHeight;
this.$refs.filter.style.height = "0";
```

You may have to work out conflicts between the template and the inline JavaScript (I can't tell because you don't show your template.), but that should get you started.